# Retrieve data based on the app selected language

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

My app is almost ready, but there is an issue I'm not sure how to approach which is my app supports Arabic and English. English is the main language of the app and users can change it from within app settings. my app provides services with name, price, and description that are in English. What I'm trying to do is when the user changes the app language the Arabic data gets retrieved, so If I added another document for name, price, and description for the Arabic version. will be able to get the data? I'll share a screenshot and some code.
Note: I'm working with Java

this one to get the service data from firebase and load them into a recylerview, I have an adapter and a model, which contain the name, price and decription.

```
Query query = db.collection("ServiceInfo");
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ServiceModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ServiceModel>()
            .setQuery(query, ServiceModel.class).build();
    adapter = new ServiceAdapter(options);
```

this is how my database is structured
[image]

[image]

thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: the code snippet I shared works fine I added it so everyone knows how I retrieve the data from firebase.

Comment: I updated the question. check it again please

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Are you asking how to configure your firebase to support multiple languages? i.e. if the App is configured for french, read the French version of the data, if the app is English, read the English version of the data, Arabic, read Arabic version of the data? If that's the case, one option is to store the language specific text within the same document and once the document is read, use the text in the corresponding fields for your UI. So rename the fields to `descriptionEn` (for English), `descriptionFr` for French etc. If that's not the question, can you clarify the question?

Comment: yes, That is my question.

Comment: I'll share my adapter and model code. then you can help me better as what needs to be adjusted.

Comment: @AlexMamo you can check his comment please

Comment: The answer provided by @AlexMamo is on point and matches my above comment. Be sure to accept that answer once you've got it working.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get it working. I cant till now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to configure your Firebase app to support multiple languages, meaning to display the data according to what the user selected as the preferred language, then you have to change the structure of the document a little bit.

This means that if the app is configured for English, you should display the data in English, if the app is configured for Arabic, you should display the data in Arabic, and so on. To achieve such functionality, the document should contain the data translated into all available languages. So document schema should look like this:

```
db
|
--- ServiceInfo (collection)
     |
     --- $docId (document)
          |
          --- name: "Advice"
          |
          --- price: 5
          |
          --- description (map)
               |
               --- en: "text in English"
               |
               --- fr: "text in French"
               |
               --- de: "text in German"
```

As you can see, the `description` is not a field of type string but a field of type `map`. This means that when you display the data, you have to check first what language is selected by the user and then dig into the map field to get the data that corresponds to the selected language.

Comment: I understand. I'll try the solution and get back to you.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: I was trying to implement it but didn't work out. your logic to the solution is correct but I can't seem to be able to code the solution. I updated the question with my Language Helper class and my Adapter. @ALexMamo

Comment: "didn't work out" doesn't provide enough information so I can help. Besides that, asking a follow-up question is typically a new post. That's the reason why I rolled back your updated question. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: What I mean by that. coding wise. it's from my end not yours I didn't provide the solution I tried cuz the errors. I'm still trying other solutions as it has nth to do with the firebase structure you provided since its correct from the provided explanation. I just wanted to update you as we agreed on. I'll work on a sol and update you again. I

Comment: Yep, keep me posted. If I can help you with other information regarding the initial question, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much @AlexMamo, I forgot that I had to update my adapter and model to match the map as well. everything now works as it should.